# Finder shows malicious application, Terminal does not

Tags: mac, terminal, finder

I'm having a problem trying to delete an application from my Mac. The file in question "Υπομνήσεις.app" is visible in Finder and Launchpad, but it won't show in the Terminal.

[image: Malicious file in Finder]

[image: Untraceable file in terminal]

`ls -a` doesn't reveal the hidden file, I tried to search my entire drive after it and I tried this too `touch Υπομνήσεις.app; rm Υπομνήσεις.app` which didn't work either. I have also checked in my own user’s applications directory (`~/Applications/`) as well as the root applications directory (`/Applications/`). I'm at a loss.

Comment: Done already, neither applications folder contains the file. I searched my entire drive after "Υπομνήσεις*" too. No result.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself, but can't quite understand it.

I opened the Package content of `Υπομνήσεις.app` and was able to remove everything in it. After doing so `Υπομνήσεις.app` renamed itself to `Reminder.app` and I was able to find it in the terminal and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Υπομνήσεις just means Remember in Greek so I don't think anything points to it being malicious.

The name is probably being set via a plist or some other metadata. Either way you should be able to remove it just with the menu you shouldn't need to remove it via the terminal.